# How to generate an AsyncPageable (from another AsyncPageable)

Tags: c#, azure, azure-sdk-.net, azure-sdk

I am creating a library that uses a number of clients which return AsyncPageables. Most of the functions in my library convert objects from the AsyncEnumerable into some other format.
Right now, I am using System.Linq.Async, to make the conversion more or less on demand.
I want to extend that idea to pass on the utility of pagination, because the App that uses the library will benefit greatly from loading data in a paginated way.

Here is a very simple example

```cs
public IAsyncEnumerable<string> ListBlobNamesAsync()
{
   var blobPageable = _container.ListBlobsAsync();
   return blobPageble.Select(i=>i.Name); //Uses System.Linq.Async

}
```

I would like to instead convert this to another AsyncPageable that applies transform (`i=>i.Name`)

Comment: I know what an AsyncPageable is and I have read that answer on SO. I have been to the issues page of azure-sdk.  Can you elaborate on what you are convey